# BibLaTeX Prefix in Citation

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, biber

When citing an `@online` source I would like to give it the prefix "Internet: ".

For example:

> Internet: Some Internet Source 2017

Is there an easy way to accomplish this without having to define a custom command?

Comment: Does `\cite[Internet:][]{yourbibkey}` do the job for you?

Comment: Can you give us a few more pointers about the bibliography package you load at the moment and the style you use? In `biblatex` it should be no problem at all to prefix `@online` sources with 'internet:' automatically, but the devil is in the detail. It would help if you could tell us more specifically what you want. Please provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).

Comment: Your reputation points are now high enough you are allowed to vote up helpful answers. Please consider to do this with the answer below. It is the way to say "Thank You" here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the following MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{einstein,
  author  = {Albert Einstein},
  title   = {{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter Körper}. ({German}) 
             [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]},
  journal = {Annalen der Physik},
  volume  = {322},
  number  = {10},
  pages   = {891--921},
  year    = {1905},
  DOI     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004},
}
@online{ApoG,
  Address = {03.08.2013},
  Edition = {15.10.1980},
  Publisher = {juris GmbH},
  Title = {ApoG - Gesetz {\"u}ber das Apothekenwesen},
  Url = {www.juris.de/purl/gesetze/_ges/ApoG},
  Year = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    %

\usepackage[
  backend=biber, % bibtex  % bibtex or biber (prefered)
  style=numeric
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % calls bib file to create the bibliography

\begin{document}
We cite online document~\cite[Internet:][]{ApoG} or % <=================
Einstein~\cite[Internet:][page~893]{einstein}. % <======================

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The command `\cite[prenote][postnote]{key}` results---depending of the used style---in for example `[prenote 2, postnote]`.

The MWE results in:

[image]